# Using jquery to get html inside an element

Tags: jquery, innerhtml, traversal

I've been trying to get all the markup between li tags and move it to another div on the page. I have tried using html, innerhtml, and children.  But, it just returns [object Object]...

The html (highly modified for simplicity):

```
<ul>
<li class="add">I want this</li>
<li class="add">I don't want this</li>
</ul>

<div id="second">
<!-- i want to insert here -->
</div>
```

This is the most current iteration of jQuery code...

```
$('li.add').click(function() {

                    var thisitem = $(this).html();
                    $("#selections").append(thisItem);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li.add').click(function() {
    var thisitem = $(this).html();
    $("#second").append(thisitem);
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wxLgH/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also..
but dont forget to include jquery library.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

var tr3 = $(".add li").eq(1).html();
var tr4 = $(".add li").eq(2).html();

$("#second ").html('<ul>'+ tr3 +'</ul><ul>'+ tr4 +'</ul>');

$(".add li").eq(1).hide();
$(".add li").eq(2).hide();

});
</script>
```